# In JavaScript button events, how do I avoid code duplication (when every button has similar functions)

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to find out how to avoid
using duplicate code for event listeners.

I have a html page with a few buttons.

In this example with 2 buttons, (id'd **trip_1** and **trip_2** ) I want to have the button
flash blue when clicked and then move on to the next step of the code after a few milliseconds

The code works, but has too much repitition.

Here I get a const for every button and then add an event listener
to it. The listener does almost the same.

Is there a recommended way to avoid writing repeated listeners for every button?

I'd prefer having a single event listener listen to all buttons and then react to the one pressed.

```
let step_change_ms = 250

function setCurrentStep(step) {
  // removed, this function hides the elements not in use and
  // shows the currently needed ones
}

const tripButton1 = document.getElementById('trip_1');
tripButton1.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    tripButton1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

    buttons_active = false;
    myBooking.trips = 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        setCurrentStep('step4')
    }, step_change_ms);
    setTimeout(function () {
        tripButton1.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }, step_change_ms);
});

const tripButton2 = document.getElementById('trip_2');
tripButton2.addEventListener('click', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    tripButton2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    buttons_active = false;
    myBooking.trips = 2;
    setTimeout(function () {
        setCurrentStep('step4')
    }, step_change_ms);
    setTimeout(function () {
        tripButton2.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }, step_change_ms);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (although I don't love splitting the id to get the number, but this is the general idea):

```js
let step_change_ms = 250

function setCurrentStep(step) {
  // removed, this function hides the elements not in use and
  // shows the currently needed ones
}

const myBooking = { trips: 0 };

document.querySelectorAll('[id^=trip_]').forEach((el) => {
    const [ , num ] = el.id.split('_');
    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        buttons_active = false;
        myBooking.trips = parseInt(num);
        console.log(myBooking);
        setTimeout(function () {
            setCurrentStep('step4')
        }, step_change_ms);
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }, step_change_ms);
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="trip_1">1</button>
<button id="trip_2">2</button>
```

Or, maybe better:

```js
let step_change_ms = 250

function setCurrentStep(step) {
  // removed, this function hides the elements not in use and
  // shows the currently needed ones
}

const myBooking = { trips: 0 };
const addListener = (el, num) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        el.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        buttons_active = false;
        myBooking.trips = num;
        console.log(myBooking);
        setTimeout(function () {
            setCurrentStep('step4')
        }, step_change_ms);
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }, step_change_ms);
    });
}

addListener(document.getElementById('trip_1'), 1);
addListener(document.getElementById('trip_2'), 2);
```

```html
    <button id="trip_1">1</button>
    <button id="trip_2">2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is pretty much easy. You need to create a separate parametrized function that changes behavior based on passed parameters. As an example, you may create a factory function that takes some parameters and returns a new function (event handler). The code will look like that:

```
function createEventListener(btn, trips) {
    return function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
       buttons_active = false;
       myBooking.trips = trips;
       setTimeout(function () {
           setCurrentStep('step4')
       }, step_change_ms);
       setTimeout(function () {
          btn.style.backgroundColor = "white";
       }, step_change_ms);
    }
}
const tripButton1 = document.getElementById('trip_1');
tripButton1.addEventListener('click', createEventListener(tripButton1, 1));
const tripButton2 = document.getElementById('trip_2');
tripButton2.addEventListener('click', createEventListener(tripButton2, 2));
```

P.S. Please note, the example may have some typos as I did not verify it, but I hope that the idea is clear.

P.P.S. it is not always good to try to write DRY (https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code, but better focus on SOLID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles